# How to run initialization commands after SSH in VS Code Remote?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, remote-server, hpc, vscode-remote

**Problem**

I am trying to connect to my school's computing cluster (aka a linux server with "login node" and "computing node") using VS Code's Remote SSH, but I cannot figure out how to run a command after SSH-ing.

**Goal**

I simply want to view Python code and test some small lines in a .ipynb jupyter notebook in the computing platform's environment.

**Description**

Basically, normally in the command line (or mobaXterm of a Windows machine) of my local machine, I first log onto the computing platform's login node with `ssh -Y -L PORT:127.0.0.1:PORT username@computing.cluster.ip`, and then run `srun -t 0-12:00 --pty -p gpu --gres=gpu:1 --x11 --tunnel PORT:PORT /bin/bash` to log onto the computing node interactively (shown command allows for port forwarding). The problem is, in VS Code I can only connect to the login node, but after that there's no way for me to run another command and log onto the computing node. The reason I need to get to computing node is that I want to test something with a .ipynb file interactively on VS Code while reading the code, and the login node does not allow me to perform computation.

**Failed trials**

I've been trying `Code-Server`, but it does not support .ipynb well (it keeps asking me to install `jupyter notebook` even though I have installed it in my conda env), possibly because it by default recognizes HPC cluster's Python interpreter which I cannot modify (I can't even select Jupyter kernel in code-server). I also tried to directly use Jupyter Notebook (open Jupyter with port forwarding after getting onto computing node), but reading code on it is much more inconvenient.

Would greatly appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: One possible workaround is that I port forward Jupyter Notebook from the computing node at the same time and use it to test small codes in .ipynb, and use VS Code to just view the code.

Comment: FYI, this seems to be the issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1722, and people have suggetsed using `RemoteCommand`.  But I am coming across other errors when using this.

Comment: Another FYI,  I opened a new [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6086) under VS Code Remote and it contains more information about my problems